# Hide the row in ssrs based on group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

[image: Current Situation]

[image: Expectation]

[image: Problem facing]

Hi , I am developing a ssrs report. And I have using two level of groups outer and inner group .

```
=IIF(RowNumber("GroupbyCategory") > 1, True, False)
```

I am trying with above code in row visibility, its working fine for single row. If the group contains more than one row, then its hide the first row. is there any possible to achieve as per expectation image. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to hide the first row in first outer group? What is the logic/condition?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is for requirement with low priority. Is it possible? no need to show the details row if that group contains only one row. So that only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve as per the expected image. You need to add the condition that hide the first row *only if* the `row count` of the inner group is 1.

```
=IIF(RowNumber("GroupbyCategory") = 1 AND CountRows("GroupbyCategory") = 1, False, True)
```

Comment: Thanks. Updated the expression.

Comment: Yes the key point is CountRows("GroupCategory") thanks... And I have altered that code as per requirement. =IIF(CountRows("GroupbyCategory") = 1, True, False)